# scanning a string to hex char array

Tags: c, string, hex, 64-bit, scanf

Here is my sample code :

```
char a;
char str [20];
unsigned char b[8] ;
unsigned char c[8];

int argsread;
int i;

init_8051();

while(1)
{
    printf("\n enter a 64 bit operation \n");

    argsread = scanf("%s", str);

    sscanf(str, "0x%x%c0x%x", b, &a, c);

    printf("\n %d arguments read \n",argsread);

        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
             printf("\n %#x %c %#x\n",b[i],a,c[i]);
}
        }

}
```

The problem here is that when i enter for example in the terminal the following input :
0x1234567890abcdef+0x1234567890abcdef

this leads to an error where output for char array is totally wrong and most of the numbers are traced into a , which should have been the plus sign , am ai doing something fundamentally wrong ?

**Update:**
I changed my code to the following :

```
while(1)
{
printf("\n enter a 64 bit operation \n");
argsread = scanf("%s", str);
sscanf(str, "0x%s%c0x%s", b, &a, c);
printf("\n %d arguments read \n",argsread);

printf("\n %s \n",b);
}
```

and i increased size of str to 30 the problem is the output of the program is :

```
 1 arguments read 

 abcdef+0xabcdef
```

so the value of b instead of being just abcdef it the the whole string!!

**Update2:**
Found this code which works perfect but i wanted to use scanf instead of cin here is the code

```
:`#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  float a, b, result;
    char oper, clear;
    cout << "Please enter an equation: i.e 5+5 " << endl;
    for (;;) {
          cin >> a;
          cin >> oper;
          cin >> b;
         if (oper == '+')
        result = a + b;
         else if (oper == '-')
            result = a - b;
       else if (oper == '*')
              result = a * b;
     else if (oper == '/')
              result = a / b;   
    cout << "= " << result << endl << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
   } 
} `
```

Comment: Is your code really formatted like this or you "didn't have time" to format it for us?

Comment: I am just writing it for like 10 minutes as i am trying to figure out how to do it , i don't format first , but i will do it for you :)

Comment: Just a friendly advice - try writing your code formatted from the beginning, instead of reformatting later. This saves time and makes finding errors/bugs easier.

Comment: Sure , i did formatted a little bit to be readable , thanks

Comment: `0x1234567890abcdef+0x1234567890abcdef` are more then 20 `chars`s. So this `argsread = scanf("%s", str);` overflows `str`.

Comment: fixed it but the problem still exists in formatting the text(update)

Comment: 0 arguments are being read are u sure [0-9a-f] is right ?

Answer (score 1):

User input and error handling much easier if code starts with `fgets()`.
Then use `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc. to parse.

```
printf("\n enter a 64 bit operation \n");
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_IOErrororEOF();

char a;
char b[17];  // use right size arrays
char c[17];
// use width of 16 and %[]
if (sscanf(buf, " 0x%16[0-9abcdef] %c 0x%16[0-9abcdef]", b, &a, c) != 3) {
  Handle_Bad_Input();
}
```

OTOH, just use an integer format specifier that allows hex input `"%x"` or `"%i"`

```
unsigned long long b,c;
if (sscanf(buf, "%lli %c%lli", &b, &a, &c) != 3) {
  Handle_Bad_Input();
}
```

---

Why `char str [20]; scanf("%s", str);` has trouble:

`"%s"` does 3 things:
1) scans, but does not save, all preceding (0 or more) white-space (`' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n '`, etc.).
2) scans and saves all non-white-space.
3) Finally reaching a white-space. it stops scanning and puts that white-space back into `stdin`.

The `"%s"` specifier lacks a width, like `"%19s"`, so it can easily overfill `str`

`sscanf(str, "0x%s%c0x%s", b, &a, c);` has trouble too.

Input has no white-space between the end of the first number and the `'+'`, so `"%s"` continues scanning.  Code does not check the return value from `sscanf()` and then uses `a`, `b`, `c`.  So `a`, `b`, `c` may not be properly scanned nor initialized - leading to potential undefined behavior .

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a string using scanf and storing it in an integer. I think that is what is causing you the problem.

Also, from the `MAN` Page

```
AME
       scanf,  fscanf, sscanf, vscanf, vsscanf, vfscanf 

       ...

RETURN VALUE

   These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched
   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
   event of an early matching failure.

   The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before  either
   the  first  successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is
   also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
   for  the  stream  (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the
   error.
```

Comment: i changed it to add to a string but still i have a problem with separating the string into sub strings depending on 0x and the plus sign

Answer (score 0):

I think you missplaced the assignment, if you want to know how many arguments matched, then change this

```
argsread = scanf("%s", str);

sscanf(str, "0x%x%c0x%x", b, &a, c);
```

to this

```
scanf("%s", str);

argsread = sscanf(str, "%x%c%x", b, &a, c);
```

According to your comments, you should change some other things, may be this code will work

```
char a;
char str [64];
unsigned int b;
unsigned int c;
char B[11];
char C[11];
int argsread;

while(1)
{
    printf("\n enter a 64 bit operation \n");

    scanf("%s", str);

    argsread = sscanf(str, "0x%x%c0x%x", &b, &a, &c);
    if (argsread == 3) 
    {
        printf("\n %d arguments read\n", argsread);

        snprintf(B, sizeof(B), "0x%08X", b);
        snprintf(C, sizeof(B), "0x%08X", c);

        printf("\n %s%c%s\n", B, a, C);
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: ok , but this is not the problem , the problem lies in "0x%x%c0x%x"

as you have seen in my update the b array takes all the input and its not limited by 0x , as my input string should be divided into 3 sub strings 2 are starting with 0x and the middle is the sign operation

Comment: i need to stroe them in a char array so i changed it to "0x%s%c0x%s" but still it doesnt work , see the update.Thanks

Comment: A string is a null terminated array of `char` so the middle `char` would be considered part of the string and `scanf` will consume the whole input thus returning `1`.

Comment: @Omarshaaban check my new answer update, does this work for you.

Comment: Minor:  The `"0x"` in `"0x%x..."` is not needed.  `"%x"` will consume the leading "0x".