# Hex calculator , parsing string using scanf

Tags: c, hex, calculator, scanf, 8051

Here is my Code :

```
char a[18], b[18];
char oper, clear;
char *test;
init_8051();

    test="0x1234567890123456 + 0x1234567890123456\0";
    printf("Please enter an equation: %s \n",test );

    sscanf(test,"0x%s %c 0x%s",a,&oper,b);

    printf(" a= %s \n" ,a);
    printf(" oper= %s \n" ,oper);
    printf(" b= %s \n" ,b);
```

I want to accept to hex numbers with an operation as a string and to be able to seperate those 2 numbers into 2 separate char arrays but it doesnt wanna work, here is the output of the following code :

```
   Please enter an equation: 0x1234567890123456 + 0x1234567890123456  
 a= 1234567890123456 
 oper= Ò 
 b= 1234567890123456
```

As you can see the operation is not recognized and also i have to use spaces which i wish i didnt have to use i wish it to be in the format of 0x1234567890123456+0x1234567890123456
with no spaces between the plus and the number.

Thanks

Comment: didn't read all the code but I can see an error here `oper` is a `char` and not a pointer to a char  So `printf(" oper= %s \n" ,oper);` must be `printf(" oper= %c \n" ,oper);`

Comment: I am not sure if there is any difference, but you are using `%s` for `char`, and putting tokenization into `scanf` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Voting to close: This is slight variation of your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566148/scanning-a-string-to-hex-char-array) that answered many of your questions.  As you did not follow the 3 answers there, it is suspect you will follow the answers here>

Answer (score 1):

From the `sscanf` manual

```
   s      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the
          terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.
```

It means that `%s` consumes the `+` and the rest of the characters, leaving `b` and `oper` uninitalized, abd overflowing `a` since it only has space for `18` characters.

So when the input string is lacking the space after the first operand, `sscanf` will continue reading until it finds a whitespace character. Hence when the string does not contain the separating space between the operands and the operator, `sscanf` consumes all the input.

I'll append here a different approach to your problems solution

1. We copy the string, this is required by [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) you can't pass an inmutable string, there  are plenty of methods to copy this string, you just have to pick the appropriate one for your case

   ```
   input = strdup("0x1234567890123456 + 0x1234567890123456\0");
   ```
2. Now, we use [strpbrk](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk) to find the operator

   ```
   pointer = strpbrk(input, "+-*/" /* here go the operators */);
   if (pointer != NULL)
       oper = *pointer; /* this will contain the operator ascii value */
   ```
3. Create a string containing the operator as a delimiter

   ```
   operstr[0] = oper;
   operstr[1] = '\0'; /* strings must be null terminated */
   ```
4. Now, we use [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to tokenize the string, and find the operands

   ```
   pointer = strtok(input, operstr);
   if (pointer != NULL)
       fprintf(stderr, "first operand: %s\n", pointer); /* you can copy this string if you need to */
   printf("Operator: %s \n", operstr);
   ```
5. Second call to [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) needs `NULL` first argument

   ```
   pointer = strtok(NULL, operstr);
   if (pointer != NULL)
       fprintf(stderr, "second operand: %s\n", pointer); /* you can copy this string if you need to */
   ```
6. And finally `free` our copy of the input string.

   ```
   free(input);
   ```

It is better to use [strtok_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) the reentrant version. But for now you could test my suggestions and may be, it is what you need.

Even though this will work for this particular situation it is not the preferred way of doing this kind of thing, you can try writing a parser and use  [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), or you can try with a lexical analyzer and a parser generator like [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67350/discussion-between-chux-and-iharob).

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was downvoted, and didn't address all of OP's requirements, so I have rewritten this answer.

OP wants flexible input, either spaces or no spaces. I suggest not using `sscanf()` but the methods below. First the program finds a valid operator by using `strcspn()`, then breaks the string using `strtok()` on operators and whitespace. But using `strtok()` on a string literal is UB so I copy the "equation" to another string first.

I also corrected the `printf()` field spec for the operator, and made `a` and `b` different - it's always a bad idea using the same values for different variables in an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define  OPERATORS "+-*/"
#define  DELIMS    " \t\n" OPERATORS

int parse (char *test)
// return 1 if parsed successfully
{
    char a[50], b[50];
    char oper;
    char *ptr;
    int opind;
    opind = strcspn (test, OPERATORS);  // find operator
    if (opind < 1) return 0;            // fail
    oper = test[opind];                 // collect operator
    ptr = strtok (test, DELIMS);        // find a
    if (ptr == NULL) return 0;          // fail
    strcpy (a, ptr);                    // collect 1st arg
    ptr = strtok (NULL, DELIMS);        // find b
    if (ptr == NULL) return 0;          // fail
    strcpy (b, ptr);                    // collect 2nd arg
    printf(" a    %s \n" ,a);
    printf(" oper %c \n" ,oper);        // corrected format
    printf(" b    %s \n" ,b);
    return 1;
}

int main (void)
{
    char test[100];
    strcpy (test, "0x123456789ABCDEF0+0xFEDCBA9876543210");
    if (!parse (test))
        printf("Failed\n");
    printf("\n");

    strcpy (test, "0x123456789ABCDEF0 + 0xFEDCBA9876543210");
    if (!parse (test))
        printf("Failed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
a    0x123456789ABCDEF0
oper +
b    0xFEDCBA9876543210

a    0x123456789ABCDEF0
oper +
b    0xFEDCBA9876543210
```